# Locomotive Bogie U shape bracket modelling

Tags: modeling

I'm working on bogies for my locomotive model and I'm kinda stumped at how best to approach this shape:
[image]

[image]

That center U shaped piece the springs sit on, how would you recommend modelling it?

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with some bevels:

- Create the profile (use a *Mirror* modifier as it is symmetetrical):

[image]

- Begin to bevel the vertices (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel vertices, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and click the *Vertices* option in the *Operator* box):

[image]

- Do the same with all the vertices (keep the same amount of segments):

[image]

- Fill the faces (it's fast if you fill the first face then only keep one edge selected and press <kbd>F</kbd> several times):

[image]

- Extrude, bevel the edges, etc...

Comment: That works beautifully! Thank you muchly! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a Bézier curve to imitate the shape, or if precision is not required, do a bridge edge loop on some square loops set up at the critical points.